# GCC error control and incompatible pointer type

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

When working with gcc I often get errors like:

"passing argument 1 of 'function' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]"

I want this warning to be an error.  I have set -fdiagnostics-show-option but that just gets me "[enabled by default]".  Does anyone know how to set this to be an error.  Right now -Werror is not really an option.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this issue or are you still stuck? If my answer did not solve it please leave a comment so we can try something else.

Answer (score 0):

You do want werror, jusr a variant of it. If you use it as werror=error-name it will turn a single warning into an error. So in your case use -Werror=strict-aliasing

However if you have an older version of gcc this may not work and you will need to use -Werror -Wno-error=all instead.